# Powershell Combine Get-ADUser Results

Tags: powershell, active-directory, hashtable, powershell-4.0

I have a script used to manage group memberships, but am running into a challenge when it comes to searching multiple OU's.

Currently, within the script, I have the following code used to query AD:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $LDAPString -SearchBase $SearchOU

(...)

Foreach ($User in $Users) 
{
    If ($User.distinguishedName -notin $Members.distinguishedName) 
    {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupDN -Members $User.distinguishedName -Server $DomainController
    }
}
```

So far, I have tried the following, where $OU is an array of OU's, but I end up with just the first result.

```
Foreach ($OU in $SearchOUs)
{
    $Users += Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $LDAPString -SearchBase $OU
}
```

Is there an easy way to combine the resulting hash tables or is it best to simply create a new hash table and add results to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt is close. Try adding `$Users = @()` before the `Foreach`. The `+=` operator is overloaded, so it can pick the wrong operation. Initializing the variable to an empty array makes it clear what you want:

```
$Users = @()
Foreach ($OU in $SearchOUs)
{
    $Users += Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $LDAPString -SearchBase $OU
}
```

Also, it's an array, not a hashtable. Those are distinct.

Comment: You're a genius! It seems my hold-up was with the assumption that it was a hashtable and not an array. I had tried something very similar by adding `$Users = @{}`.  Either way, your suggestion won the battle.  Thanks much!

Comment: @JasonW If you ever need to test what a group is like that, you can always use `$x -is [hashtable]` or `$x -is [array]` where `$x` is whatever you're working with.

Comment: Well hey, look at that little knowledge nugget... I'll definitely be keeping this in my toolbox. Thanks!